# Case-insensitive view over a case-sensitive file system?

Tags: macos, filesystem, apfs

[Steam for macos](https://store.steampowered.com/macos) doesn't work on a case-sensitive file system. A common solution is to create a dedicated virtual image and mount it as a volume.

However, because my such image is running out of space, I was wondering if some mean exists (eg, based on FUSE) to mount a volume on top of an existing one, to expose a case-insensitive view of the large HD partition I normally use for everything.